# Парсинг сайа на PHP

Tags: php, парсер

Есть большой вопрос нужно спарсить email, вроде все просто, но чтобы спарсить email нужно пройти капчу, но не простую, там не нужно ничего вводить. Вот сайт craigslist.org вот пример объявления https://newyork.craigslist.org/mnh/res/d/legal-guru-seeking-part-time-remote/6843839994.html

Надо кликнуть сюда http://joxi.ru/krDOVqvSKgBq0A и выведет емейл пользователя.
Перепробовал кучу всего cUrl, phpQuery. Там непонятно где сама google recaptcha.

Comment: Я сам далеко не с первого раза могу доказать Google.ReCaptcha что я не робот )))